# Can we use request.get parameter from ajax in servlet?

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, request

can we get variable from ajax as request.getparameter in Servlet?

Answer (score 1):

you can use it.

Use query parameter.

```
function action(arg0) {

$.ajax({
    url: '/test',
    type: 'get'   // 'get' or 'post'
    data: 'arg0=' + arg0,  //variable you want to send.
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);            
    }

}); }
```

in Servlet

```
request.getParameter("arg0")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As just like your query parameter. You can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but make sure you pass the name of the parameter the same as which you use in ajax data.